# Using LDAP for authentication in iOS

Tags: ios, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I have been looking for a tutorial on using LDAP on an iOS device is this possible? I havent seen any articles or tutorials on it. Is there another way I should be going about doing authentication against my Active Directory? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to Google up a few answers for you.

[Integrating LDAP into an iPhone application](http://www.rhussmann.com/2009/08/integrating-ldap-into-an-iphone-application/)

[LDAP and the iPhone](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-iphoneapp/?ca=drs-)

And LDAP is even supported within Apple libraries & code, like the [iOS configuration profile](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 10):

I have a port of OpenLDAP with Cyrus-SASL and OpenSSL in my iOS Ports project: https://github.com/bindle/iOSPorts

If using Xcode 4.3 or later, please verify that the Xcode commandline tools are installed before using the following instructions.

To include LDAP support:

1. Clone the project: git clone `git://github.com/bindle/iOSPorts.git`
2. Add the project file `iOSPorts/ports/database/openldap/openldap.xcodeproj` to your Xcode project.
3. Navigate to the "Build Phases" tab for your build target.
4. In "Target Dependencies", add "ldap (openldap)".  This will cause the required source code to be downloaded and compiled when you build your target.
5. In "Link Binary With Libraries", add the following libraries:

   - libresolv.dylib
   - libssl.a
   - libcrypto.a
   - liblber.a
   - libldap.a
   - libsasl2.a
6. Under the "Build Settings", add "/iOSPorts/include" to the "User Header Search Paths".

The OpenLDAP client libraries should now be available from within your project.  I have an example project for iOS in examples/database/openldap/ldapsearch (the example returns the search results using NSLog()).

Comment: Your LDAP example app is broken for XCode 4.3.2 (Lion) by default.  The fix is to go into XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads and Install the command line utilities needed for the makefiles.

Comment: @rwyland  I've updated the post to include information for Xcode 4.3.

Comment: @MuseerAhamadAnsari Can u help me on this?