# Windows Phone 8 and Active Directory Authentication

Tags: active-directory, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a windows phone 8 app, I want to link the app user's accounts with their accounts in an active directory.

Is there a way/SDK/service that enables the users to communicate with the active directory server to make use of the roles and identities ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A newer approach is to use Azure Active Directory to host (or mirror) your AD roles and identities then make them accessible via an API for apps to consume...

1. [Setting up an Active Direct Forest in Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/active-directory-forest/)
2. [Setting up REST Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn169448.aspx) (can be used with Windows Store apps)
3. [Calling REST Services from a Windows Phone 8 app](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/04/29/fun-with-windows-azure-ad-calling-rest-services-from-a-windows-phone-8-app/)

Other options include...

1. Exposing and communicating with [Active Directory's LDAP service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877233/using-ldap-for-authentication-in-ios)
2. Using [LDAP Authentication with PHP for Active Directory](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: But if other platforms (Android, iOS) manage to do all that without Azure then it's strange the Microsoft can't do it in his devices without installing additional servers. In this case company's IT will just say that WP8 is not allowed to be used within company.

Comment: Are there AD authentication libs for iOS and Android? the approach I mention involves creating a web service / api which any app from any platform can talk to.