# Objective C LDAP Authentication

Tags: objective-c, c, ldap

I am very new to Objective C and learning as I go.

What I am looking for is a way to have 2 text fields be sent to my LDAP server, if the password matches. I would like to pull information about that user, such as office, description or anything I might want to know about the user.

I have read a lot about OpenLDAP and it doesn't look like it can do this from what I have been reading.

Is there a better way to do this?

Basically here is what I want sudo code

```
text.get(username)
pass.get(password)
if(password.equals(LDAP Server Credentials)
   description = person.description
   firstname = person.firstname
   jobTitle = person.jobTitle
```

That is all I am looking for any help, suggestions would be great, keep in mind although I know other languages I just started on objective C about 3 days ago and although I am learning a lot, I am not an expert at the language at all.

Hoping for some good help is all!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877233/using-ldap-for-authentication-in-ios for some background into OpenLDAP on iOS.

Comment: That is very outdated unfortunately....It doesn't work good(or at all) for the newest version of IOS and Xcode

Comment: Did you find any luck, as my requirement is also the same.

Comment: Any luck guys? Same problem.