# Implementing LDAP on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ldap

I am working on a project that needs to be able to use LDAP to download information about contacts. Does anyone know of a library that will let me do this fairly painlessly.

I have looked into openLDAP (specifically the iOSPorts version [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877233/using-ldap-for-authentication-in-ios/7877908#7877908)) but it has been a nightmare trying to get it to compile with the latest version of xcode.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877233/using-ldap-for-authentication-in-ios

Comment: Downloaded, installed and worked without issue on the latest *released* version of XCode

Comment: I have been working with the unreleased version but I will give the other one a shot. @BadWolf I did link that question but specified that I could not get the solution to work for me