# LDAP authentication for mobile application in Titanium

Tags: active-directory, ldap, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm new to Titanium as well as authentication with LDAP

I need to connect to my client network where there will be an Active Directory. I need to authenticate the user for my mobile app which is in Titanium with the Active Directory in my client network through LDAP.

I have no idea how to authenticate through LDAP. Need some help for this task.
I need to do this in Titanium.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

[You can use a module to do that.](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5251?1421641027)

Also, if you dont have enterprise access, you can roll-your-own LDAP module, using [these resources.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877911/874257)