# Integrating LDAP library in iOS App getting Undefined Symbol Architechture error

Tags: ios, ldap, openldap

I am trying to integrate LDAP library in my iOS project. There is not much detailed solutions available on the Internet regarding this, except a few.

I found OpenLdap completely dedicated towards this. But they have not updated their library for past 5 years.

After searching so much I got a [link](https://github.com/bindle/iOSPorts) which describe how to integrate LDAP protocol in iOS App. I follow the same procedure what has been written, but I am facing lots of error in the LDAP library itself, May be it had been written on very old Xcode and iOS version.

After changing it in the Xcode settings and configuring it for the latest iOS version I am getting "Undefined symbol architecture error i386".

Image 1:[image]

In the first Image I found the predefined methods which is being used in ldap library are not available in iOS, it is only available in OSX

Image 2: [image]

Here the error what I am getting all are "Undefined symbol architecture error, I have almost 20 errors on this, Please help me to get rid from this.

1.Please help me how to fix these errors and successfully integrate in iOS app.

2.I want to know that Whether ldap is supporting iOS app?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Walk through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877233/using-ldap-for-authentication-in-ios

Comment: I already have followed this link but no luck, Same above error I am getting everytime. Do you have any kind of Demo Projects in which you have done simliarly like this?

Comment: No,not yet to do the demo project