# Are their any LDAP iOS Authentication SDK available?

Tags: ios, ldap

I am looking for a demo to support LDAP authentication in my iOS app.

Seems like the one which are currently available are too damn old to work on, already tried:
[Using LDAP for authentication in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877233/using-ldap-for-authentication-in-ios)

Is something like UnboundID available for iOS? 
https://github.com/pingidentity/server-sdk-maven

Anything will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only SDK that I was able to easily google up was [Bindle's LdapKit](https://github.com/bindle/LdapKit) (which also requires their companion [iOSPorts repo](https://github.com/bindle/iOSPorts) to be installed in the same folder).

As you've already discovered, they haven't updated LdapKit in over five years at this point.  Hopefully you (or somebody else) will be able to get LdapKit updated to the point where it will be easily compile-able again.  If you do, don't forget to fork and then open a pull request back to Bindle's repos to merge in your open source changes!